# Is there any way to get Google Sheets fileid from file picker intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-sheets-api

In my Android app I would like the user to open a Google Sheets document to import data from it into the app database.

1. It's easy to select a file with `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` / `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and with MIME filter `application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet`. (It will be a virtual file.)
2. It's also easy to get the content of a Google Sheets document with the Google Sheets API based on the Drive filed id (with user-granted `spreadsheets.readonly` scope):

```
Sheets.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, appCredential)
   .build()
   .spreadsheets()
   .get(fileid)
   .execute()
```

But the first step returns the **Uri of the file** on the device, and the second step requires the **file id of the Drive file**.
How can I determine the second from the first?

The only poor solution I found was to use the Google Drive API: I search the Sheets file with its name I got from the intent, and I get the id of it... It requires the `drive.metadata.readonly` scope, which is a restricted scope, and doh... it's not a viable solution anyway...
I can download a pdf from the uri of the virtual file, but it's not suitable for importing data.

If anyone knows the answer, a thousand thanks for it!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the type of `fileId` is. (I am not familiar with that particular API).

In general, you need to use `ContentResolver` to convert the `Uri` into some usable type such as `InputStream`, `FileDescriptor`, etc.

There is also the [DocumentFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/documentfile/provider/DocumentFile) utility class to work with Document URIs.

Comment: The Google drive fileId